# Laravel Eloquent to get parent, child records and child records

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have these models having the following fields enclosed in brackets.
User can have many post and post can have many categories.  How can we
achieve to get these using laravel eloquent.

```
User   [id, name]
Post   [id, user_id, post_title]
PostType [id,post_id, category_desc]
```

In User model

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasmany('App\Post');
}
```

In Post model

```
public function categories(){
   return $this->hasmany('App\PostType');
}
```

In Controller

```
$result = User::with('post')->get();
```

which will return users, with each user having a records of post.  But how to add the categories in the results set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include distant relations with dot notation:

```
$result = User::with(['post', 'post.categories'])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Devon, tested and working as expected.  You're a guru.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution, especially if you want to bring the posts and post categories every time you grab the user, would be to use the $appends array on the User and Post model to automatically pull those relationships with every query. For example, your Post model would include this at the top:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    $appends = array('categories');
...
```

And your User model would look something like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    $appends = array('posts');
...
```

This will automatically pull in those categories along with the posts any time you pull in a User object.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution eResourcesInc.  Will take note of this as well.