# Laravel select row and its child rows

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-9

As a Laravel beginner,

I have a `gallery` table as follows

```
id     |     gallery_name    | published
-------+---------------------+------------
1      |    name             |  1
-------+---------------------+------------
2      |    name 2           |  1
-------+---------------------+------------
```

And another table ( `gallery_images`) to store images associated with each gallery

```
id   |   gal_id    |   image_name
-----+-------------+--------------
1    |   1         | image_01
-----+-------------+--------------
2    |   1         | image_02
-----+-------------+--------------
3    |   2         | image_03
-----+-------------+--------------
```

In my controller fetching the gallery by the following code

```
$data['galleries']= Gallery::where('published','=',1)->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
```

Showing the gallery in view like this.

```
@foreach($data['galleries'] as $gal)
    <h3>{{$gal['gallery_name']}}</h3>
    <p>{!! html_entity_decode($gal['gallery_text']) !!}</p>
    // Show images associated with each gallery
@endforeach
```

Now I need to show images associated with each `gallery` from `gallery_images`.

What is the best practice to call a function from view ? or are there any other ways?

Comment: This could be helpful for you I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377222/laravel-eloquent-to-get-parent-child-records-and-child-records it's showing you how to select Parent with Child records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a one-to-many relationship, add this function in `gallery` model:

```
public function galleryImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(gallery_images::class, 'gal_id');
}
```

Now change your `view` file:

```
@foreach($data['galleries'] as $gal)
    <h3>{{$gal['gallery_name']}}</h3>
    <p>{!! html_entity_decode($gal['gallery_text']) !!}</p>
    @foreach($gal->gallerImages as $image)
        // Show image associated with $gal
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```